# Is it possible to disable the hot corners in mac with a script?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working with an electron app and I have a task about disabling the hot corners in Mac with a script. I am quite new in the subject so I am wondering if anyone around have already dealt with a similar situation.

When launching the app, the electron window does not take the full width but it is something we could implement if the hot corners can get to be disabled this way.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Highly doubt it would be possible

Comment: This would be a UX nightmare - most users would struggle to figure out why their hot corners have been disabled, especially when disabled without their knowledge or explicit intention of doing so. Please reconsider this requirement - plenty of apps "*take the full width*" without needing to resort to overriding user preferences.

Comment: @epascarello do you have any doc-page-fundamental knowledge that would answer why it's not possible? :/ I don't seem to find clear information about this -- and they are asking me to fix this ticket asap!

Comment: @esqew I missed key information -- the app is "secure" meanwhile it is open, meaning: the user knows the shortcuts and normal stuff for the computer are blocked, so UX wise would not be surprising!

Comment: I don't think you could change the system settings through the app. Best you could get would be opening system preferences.

Comment: "*so UX wise would not be surprising*" I would disagree wholeheartedly - overriding default functionality users would expect *normally* in the first place is inherently poor UX. What does "*the app [being] "secure"*" have *anything* to do with the user experience?

Comment: @esqew it is meant to work like this, it is fully explained to the user in order to prevent him from opening other apps or windows while using this app.

Comment: @foreignChimichurri Sounds a lot like malware to me. What exactly is your use case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "safe" way of doing this that doesn't run the risk of indefinitely disabling your users' hot corners. ***If your program crashes or is otherwise terminated unexpectedly, you absolutely should ensure that there is some contingency to reset these keys back to their original values***. I would go so far as to say this is absolutely **not a recommended approach** and that these types of UX-modifying hacks are way less than ideal.

If you must do so, you can probably get away with doing something via [`node-applescript`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript):

```
const applescript = require('applescript');
var hotCorners = {
    'wvous-bl-corner': null,
    'wvous-bl-corner-modifier': null,
    'wvous-br-corner': null,
    'wvous-br-modifier': null,
    'wvous-tl-corner': null,
    'wvous-tl-modifier': null,
    'wvous-tr-corner': null,
    'wvous-tr-modifier': null
}


// read current default values first
Object.keys(hotCorners).forEach(key => hotCorners[key] = applescript.execString(`do shell script "defaults read com.apple.Dock ${key}"`));

// overwrite with zeros to disable hot corner functionality
Object.keys(hotCorners).forEach(key => applescript.execString(`do shell script "defaults write com.apple.Dock ${key} -int 0"`));
```

And at the point when you wish to write these configurations back:

```
Object.keys(hotCorners).forEach(key => applescript.execString(`do shell script "defaults write com.apple.Dock ${key} -int ${hotCorners[key] ?? 0}"`));
```

You should also take care to write the current configuration to a less-ephemeral storage medium than RAM; easiest way to do that would be to write the JSON structure to a file within your Electron app (or to storage elsewhere on the client device).

The success of this method will depend on several factors relating to the macOS version and security posture of the client device and the user themselves (whether they accept any security prompts relating to this functionality in later versions of macOS). As such you should also be implementing error checking with this type of functionality to ensure that you can properly react to unexpected conditions.

In the interest of full disclosure, I no longer have access to a macOS machine to test this on; as such this code is *untested* and I do not guarantee its success in any capacity - use this guidance at your own peril.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I will bring it to discussion as an absolute not-safe way of doing something and try to change their minds about it. Thanks really, I was really looking for a technical way for backing up this point.

Comment: For your reference, there is probably a more direct route to calling `defaults` using the `child_process` module, but this is the first way that came to mind. You may try to mix it up between these two (and other) strategies to get to where you need to be considering the requirement, the target systems' security postures, etc.